# Describing a vector field

Tags: fourier-analysis, vector

I am currently making use of a 2D vector field that I would like to be able to describe and characterize. I thought of a few metrics that I could use, but they seem limited for both a qualitative and quantitative analysis.

I believe that the divergence and curl of the field would be interesting. The vector field could also be mapped with a 2D polynomial function as well as harmonics using 2D Fourier Transform.

Do you happen to know other tools to describe or decompose a vector field?

Comment: you could compute the interpolating polynomial for the x and y components of the field, then use basic calculus identities on the polynomials to compute div and curl

Comment: What is the purpose of your characterization, what are you expecting?

Comment: I want to be able to recreate it without holding all the numerical values of the 2D array.
Then I want to discriminate potential rotations from translations motion in an optical flow field.

Comment: Each vector is described by a pair of numbers (x,y). Why not use the distribution function (or just a few of its first moments) of (x,y) to describe the main features of this 2D data set. From the distribution function one can produce a data set with similar properties.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of this distribution function?